# What causes fotran ranks not matching error

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have no experience with fortran, but I need to define the variable `error`.

`a = 3.086e18`

`error = ABS(((xCoord / a)**2 + (9 / 4)*(yCoord / a)**2 + (zCoord / a)**2 -1)**3 - (xCoord / a)**2 * (yCoord / a)**3 - (9 / 200) * (yCoord / a)**2 * (zCoord / a)**3)`

When I run the code, I get the `Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment` error.

I don't know anything about fortran and this issue is probably trivial. Can you please tell me where's the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We especially need to know the definitions of `xCoord, yCoord, zCoord`.

Comment: I found this at the beginning of the file: real,allocatable,dimension(:) :: xCoord,yCoord,zCoord

Comment: If `xCoord`, `yCoord` and `zCoord` are arrays then the term on the right would be an array. The variable `error` is a scalar so it's impossible to do. You need to declare `error` as you declared `xCoord̀` for example (as an array).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example (inspired from your code) in order to understand better:

```
! example.f90

program main
  implicit none
  integer,dimension(2)::array !< Declaration of the array 
  real::a=3.086e18
  real::error !< Scalar 
  integer::i
  do i=1,2
     array(i)=1 !< Initialization of the array  
  end do
  error=array/a
  print*,error
end program main
```

Output:

```
11 |   error=array/a
      |  1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)
```

The problem is that `error` is a scalar while `array/a` is an array of 2 elements (as the declaration of array). You canno't store an array in a scalar (obviously).

In order to make it work you need to declare error as an array of 2 elements like this:

```
  real,dimension(2)::error
```

Output:

```
 3.24044050E-19   3.24044050E-19
```

Answer (score 1):

So please try to include more details in your question. Specifically variable declarations, function arguments and expected output.

In this case, calculations in Fortran are vectorized, applying the same math formula to all elements of an array. Because `xCoord` is a vector, then any math formula involving `xCoord` would result in a vector.

To fix your error, you might want to keep only the largest value from the result. You do this with the **[`maxval()`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/m-to-n/maxval.html)** function

```
error = maxval(abs(((xCoord / a)**2 + (9 / 4d0)*(yCoord / a)**2 &
        + (zCoord / a)**2 -1)**3 - (xCoord / a)**2 * (yCoord / a)**3 &
        - (9 / 200d0) * (yCoord / a)**2 * (zCoord / a)**3))
```

Also note that `(9 / 4)` results in `2` not `2.25` as the compiler assumes you want integer division. To correct it type `(9 / 4d0)`.

PS. `Fortran` = `For`mula `Tran`slation which exactly this process of applying a formula to all elements of an array.